# If $lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f'(x) = 0$ does $f(x)$ have a limit for $x \rightarrow \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis

As the title suggests,
If the limit of the derivative of the function tends to 0 for large x's, does this imply that the there does exist a finite limit for f(x) as x tends for large x's?

It feels intuitevly right. I'm thinking if f(x) wouldn't have a finite limit for large x's, and thus going off to either positive or negative infinity, we would never be able to get a derivative that tends to 0 for large x's.

I'd be glad if some of you could provide a proof if this statement is correct. Thak you.

Comment: What about $f(x) = \sqrt x$?

Comment: Thank you, that'll certainly be enough :)

Comment: Another counterexample: $f(x)=\log(x)$.

Comment: Note that your question is more or less equivalent to asking if $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) = 0$ implies that the  integral $\int_0^\infty g(x) dx$ exists – which is also not true.

Comment: Thanks @MartinR, that's a nice comparision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. This is a similar statement to "Is $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k <\infty$ if $a_n\to 0$?". In fact you can let $f'$ fall to $0$ arbitrarily slow, without such a limit existing. A quite common example would be $f'(x) = 1/x$ (we can for example have $f(x) = \log(x)$, then $f'=1/x$). It should be known that this function is not integrable on $[1,\infty)$ (also clear as $\log(x)\to\infty$).

But $1/x\to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

As a side note:
I think the unintuitiveness of the counter examples has its source in the limit.

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}f'(x) = 0$$

seems like to suggest that there is some value $x$ from which $f'(x)$ is zero. All counter examples converge towards 0. If the rate of convergence is too slow than the actual function might still increase and hence prevent a convergence of $f(x)$.